# RapidAPI having API key... can it have a common URL?

Tags: android, api, kotlin

This is the URL code I am using. It always throws me some or the other error..... I referred a lot of videos they have a common URL, so this makes me confuse to understand in this manner having seperate API key and host.....

My question was that can I have a common URL having URL and API key

```
 val url = "MY_URL"
        val response: HttpResponse<String> = Unirest
            .get(url)
            .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "API_KEY")
            .header("x-rapidapi-host", "HOST")
            .asString()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass an API key in an URL via a query parameter, for rapid api you need to :

```
https://example.p.rapidapi.com/?x-rapidapi-key=***************************
```

Comment: For some reasons they now use `rapidapi-key` and not `x-rapidapi-key`

Answer (score 0):

The `x-rapidapi-host` and `URL` are different in all the cases depending on what API you're using on RapidAPI Hub. But `x-rapidapi-key,` which is in fact, your API key, will always remain the same for all the APIs.